# How do I reference a JS variable from an external ASCX file?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net

I have a text input as a variable via JavaScript inside an HTML file. In an ascx behind the scenes of the site itself I am attempting to reference this variable at run-time based on what the user enters on the site. So the question I have is potentially two fold.

1. Is it possible to use C# in ASP.NET to access a variable in JavaScript sitting in an HTML source?
2. If it is, then how? is this done with a namespace and if so which one?

Comment: This fundimentally makes no sense.  All of the server side code executes to create the response, then that response is sent to the client, and then JavaScript code runs.  There is never any server side code running after JavaScript code runs unless it's on an entirely different request.  If you want to do something on the server after executing some JS code then use AJAX to submit a new request to the server.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand what you're trying to do.  If you're trying to access it in the code behind, then it's already been posted to the server inside of whatever control you have it in.  What exactly is the javascript doing and where and when is the variable being used?

Comment: What you're essentially asking, i believe, is "Can I send a javascript variable to my code-behind" - yep, you can. You need to look into AJAX for the Javascript side (Jquery library does the trick) and WebMethods for the server side. Basically your javascript will send an Ajax request to a method in your code-behind.

Comment: Yes I agree with @Darren. You'll have to do AJAX call

Comment: Thank you for the responses. Perhaps I should have explained differently. I'm pretty new to ASP.NET and have only become what I'd consider "acceptable" in JavaScript itself so this is a bit of a trial by fire. Basically I have a rather large website that is part of an installed web service with a desktop client that allows customization of web applications. I have a lot of client specific JavaScript incorporated and I would like to have some specific actions occur at run time within the HTML itself and I need to access my JavaScript variable(s) to do so. I am attempting to try AJAX currently.